# How $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\cdot 0^{n-k}\cdot 2^{k}=2^{n}$?

Tags: binomial-theorem

**Note:** I know this can be converted to $(0+2)^{n}=2^{n}$ according to the binomial theorem, I just got stuck after expanding the sum.

I expanded this sum and this is what I got:

$0+0+0+...+{n\choose n}\cdot 0^{0}\cdot 2^{n}$

Here, since $0^{0}$ is undefined how the sum will be equal to $2^{n}$ ?

Comment: By convention, $0^0 :=1$, which is suggested by $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } x^x  = 1$.

Comment: That (and many other formulas) it's why $0^0$ is DEFINED as $1$ in some areas of Mathematics.  I don't understand why some people insists in left it undefined...

Comment: There is several cases in limit calculation that involves the indeterminate form $0^0$, and while it is not as the same as $0^0$, it is still weird to define $0^0$ as a "number" that has multiple outcome (in view of limits).

Comment: read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it's necessary to define $0^0 = 1$ here.

Note that there are cases where it's not right to define $0^0 = 1$; for example, $\lim_{x \to 0} 0^x$ is $0$. For this reason, anywhere you have a formula which includes a term $0^0$, you need to give the value of $0^0$ alongside that formula.

Comment: But how someone can differentiate when to use $0^{0}=1$ and the limit you mentioned, because I find the limit more appropriate here as it's $0^{n-k}$ not a variable to the power of itself as "Gary" mentioned.

Comment: Well, if you do that, then the formula doesn't work! Here, you have to go back to the combinatorial intuition of $0^n$, which is where the formula ultimately came from: $0^n$ is "the number of ways to choose $n$ things from a set of $0$". That is $0$ unless $n$ is $0$, in which case it's $1$ (because there is one way to choose no items from zero items).

Comment: By which I mean it's the number of ways to draw $n$ elements with replacement, not "choose", sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use $0^0=1, 0^k=0, k\ne 0$ In the series on ly the last term contibutes :
$$(0+2)^n=0+...+0+...+0+...+0+{n \choose n} 0^{n-n} 2^n=2^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to define $0^0 = 1$ only if you use $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^{k}$.

The issue does not arise if you use $(a+b)^n=a^n+{n\choose 1}a^{n-1}b+\cdots +{n\choose n-1}ab^{n-1}+b^n$.